# Free dynamic bidimensional matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, free

I made a code which allocs 2 `int` matrices, and frees in the end, after use. When I disalloc the first matrix, it works fine. In the second, the error:

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0829a068 ***Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

I can't find where the error is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **AlocaMatriz (int linha, int coluna) {
    int **m, i, j;

    m = (int **) malloc (linha * sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        m[i] = (int *) malloc (coluna * sizeof(int ));
    }

    /*inicializa matriz*/
    for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return(m);
}

int **DesalocaMatriz (int linha, int coluna, int** m) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        free (m[i]);
    }
    free (m);
    return(NULL);
}

int main() {

    int i, j, numLinhas, numColunas, numInstancias, **matriz, **somas, resultado = 0;

    scanf("%d", &numInstancias);

    while (numInstancias > 0) {

        scanf("%d %d", &numLinhas, &numColunas);

        matriz = AlocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas);
        somas = AlocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas);

        //some operations on both matrices

        DesalocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas, matriz);
        DesalocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas, somas);
        numInstancias--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need not cast the `malloc`.

Comment: a 2D array is just freed by `free(ptr_to_2darray);`. But you don't have a 2D array in your code.

Comment: The deallocation function probably shouldn't return anything.  It doesn't really need the 'number of columns' argument — it doesn't use it, at any rate.

Comment: Using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on a minimally modified version of the code (unused variables removed, mainly – my default compilation options reject programs with unused variables) gives the code you show a clean bill of health.  As already suggested by [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023), the problem is not in the code you show, so it is most probably in the code you don't show.

Comment: @user3121023 the program runs normally. I set values on both matrix, print them, and then they are freed. I ran valgrind now and I think the problem is on malloc. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Just don't use tables of pointers to emulate a 2D matrix. Since C99, C has 2D matrixes out of the box, you allocate them with `double (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(double[n][m]));`, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the return of malloc to see if it succeeded or failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **AlocaMatriz (int linha, int coluna) {
    int **m = NULL, i, j;

    if ( ( m = malloc (linha * sizeof(int *))) != NULL) {//not NULL is success

        for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
            if ( ( m[i] = malloc (coluna * sizeof(int ))) == NULL) {//NULL is failure
                while ( i) {//free allocated so far
                    i--;
                    free ( m[i]);
                }
                free ( m);
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        /*inicializa matriz*/
        for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++) {
                m[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return(m);
}

int **DesalocaMatriz (int linha, int coluna, int** m) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
        free (m[i]);
    }
    free (m);
    return(NULL);
}

int main() {

    int i, j, numLinhas, numColunas, numInstancias, **matriz, **somas, resultado = 0;

    scanf("%d", &numInstancias);

    while (numInstancias > 0) {

        scanf("%d %d", &numLinhas, &numColunas);

        matriz = AlocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas);
        somas = AlocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas);

        //some operations on both matrix

        if ( matriz) {//if not NULL
            DesalocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas, matriz);
        }
        if ( somas) {//if not NULL
            DesalocaMatriz(numLinhas, numColunas, somas);
        }
        numInstancias--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, the problem is at malloc. But I'm not creating a huge matrix, just a 3x3 of integers. Could you tell me why isn't it working?

Comment: Yes, I read a file with integer values for the matrices, using < stdin

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a two dimensional array, you have a pointer to a pointer. In order to free the memory allocated to this array, you need to free the secondary arrays before the first array. Do it like this...

```
int **array;
int size1 = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
for(int i=0; i<size1; i++) {
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

You should also know that once a program ends, all of the allocated memory is automatically freed.

You can dynamically allocate an array by doing this...

```
array = malloc(size1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            array[i] = malloc(size2 * sizeof(int));
    }
```

This should give an array that can be accessed like this...

`array[0-size1][0-size2];`

Comment: I need to free the matrix because it will run more than one instance of the problem. It's necessary to reallocate the matrix according to the inputs.

(yes, I know it frees at the end)

Comment: @ameyCU I ran valgrind now and I think the problem is in the allocation. But I can't tell where exactly.

Comment: @PatriciaSilva You may need to check `return` of `malloc` and make sure that you don't make pointer to point at any other location between allocation and deallocation .

Comment: `int size1 = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was freeing all of the memory allocated to the pointers stored in the first dimension of the array. What should I do to fix it?